# C internal header conventions for libraries

Tags: c, header, internal, convention, project-structure

Are there any conventions for seperating the public interface headers and internal headers? I've looked at some libraries and see that mostly the internal headers are in the `src` directory named `something-internal.h` and the public headers are in the `include` directory. I was thinking of something like this:

(`xyz` is the library name)

**`include/xyz/something.h`**  (public interface)

```
struct something;
void do_something(struct something *s);
```

**`src/something.h`**  (internal header)

```
/* include public header */
#include "xyz/something.h"

/* struct definition in internal header for opaque struct */
struct something { int x, int y };
```

**`src/something.c`**

```
/* not xyz/something.h, but the private header in src/ */
#include "something.h"

void do_something(struct something *s) {
        /* function definition */
}
```

So note that I don't use the `-internal` suffix, because in my opinion if the header is in the `src` directory it's internal. Is this clear enough for, for example, new contributors? Or should the `-internal` suffix be added for clarity?

`

Comment: naming two different things with the same name is confusing

Comment: @PeterMiehle Even with the directory appended like `xyz/something.h`?

Comment: I think what you suggest is perfectly fine. The linux kernel uses a similar layout with the public `sched.h` under include/ and the private `sched.h` under kernel/sched

Comment: Alright! Then I'll use my layout. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you suggest is perfectly fine. The linux kernel uses a similar layout with the public `sched.h` under include/ and the private `sched.h` under kernel/sched – Frederik Deweerdt

Comment: if the files have same names, how do you deal with the include-guard macros? They generally have same name as the file name. The private implementation code might need to include both public and private header.

Comment: @Sam, You can use `#pragma once` or use a different macro for each file.